# How to redirect my website to a country specific URL based on user's country inside razor view Umbraco

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my razor view, I am getting the user's country origin using:

```
var userCountry = Request.Headers["CF-IPCountry"].ToLower();
```

Now based on this country I want to redirect my website URL to the specific country's url. Basically, I have 30 websites for 30 different countries.

ex: For India, my website will look like:
www.test.com/en-in.
For Australia,
www.test.com/en-au.
For New Zealand,
www.test.com/en-nz

In my razor view (Master template), I have written something like

```
Response.Redirect("https://www.test.com/en-{userCountry}");
```

This leads to an error message: "web page has too many redirects"
How to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED. I found the solution. I have used session variable to implement it.

```
       if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["userCountryAbbr"] as string))
        {
            Session["userCountryAbbr"] = userCountry;
            if(!countryList.Contains(userCountry.ToString()))
            {
              Response.Redirect("/en-ng");
            }
            else
            {
              Response.Redirect("/en-" + userCountry);
            }
        }
        else
        {
           Session["userCountryAbbr"] = "";
        }
```